# How have test project reference Maui project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, maui

I've recently jumped into cross-platform development and wanted to just bite the bullet and go straight into the newest framework that the dotnet team has started working on, MAUI.

The issue I've run into is trying to add another test project in the solution and referencing the MAUI project. As I'm pretty new to Visual Studio as well, this may just be a rookie mistake and I just don't know what I'm doing, but here I am asking away.

### What I've done:

- Created MAUI project with the default template in Visual Studio 2022 Preview 17.2.0, with target frameworks (net6.0, net6.0-android & net6.0-ios)
- Added XUnit test project on the side with target framework (net6.0)
- Added UseMaui=true as a property of the test project

I've also tried to add all the target frameworks into the project, but that causes more issues than it solves. I've tried to follow this [open source project](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.UnitTests/CommunityToolkit.Maui.UnitTests.csproj) where they got it to work, but I'm unsure how to achieve it.

### Some screenshots

[Test Project .csproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvmd0.png)

[Alt+Enter of class not being imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5ye0.png)

[Manually added import because suggestions did not add them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NgWr.png)

[Error in Test Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aye25.png)

[Test Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBBJQ.png)

Comment: In Visual Studio. Any time you need one project to reference another one in the same solution, the first step is Solution Explorer / your project / Add Reference. Doesn’t matter what kinds of projects they are. See visual studio docs. google for more details.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve hey, thanks for the reply. I've added the project as a reference and that worked fine. What's not working is referencing any of the classes from the MAUI project. See the 2nd and 3rd screenshots. Those are after referencing the MAUI project into my Test project. The following screenshot after that are errors in the Test project on the namespaces from the MAUI project.

Comment: Double-check that `using namespace` matches namespace declaration in your project. Delete test project's `bin` and `obj` folders. Make sure build target is `Windows Machine`, and the tiny triangle dropdown has `Framework (net 6.0-windows..)` selected. Make sure Configuration Manager has Test Project / Build checked. Build Test Project. Still can't find references? If so, make a public github repo that demonstrates the problem, and link to it here. Strip out anything not needed to demonstrate the failure.

Answer (score 2):

This link may be helpful.
https://www.softwaremeadows.com/posts/net_maui_progressing_from_a_default_project_part_6_-_revisiting_unit_testing/

Summary:

1. In your `.csproj` file, add 'net6.0' to TargetFrameworks as below.

   ```
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
   ```
2. Modify OutputType to use Condition.

   ```
    <OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0'">Exe</OutputType>
   ```

Comment: That don't work when it references nugets that don't have net6.0 as target

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because of mismatch in project target frameworks. Easy fix is to add Target Framework to your maui project that matches the one used in test project. For example if your Test poject is base on net6.0, just add net6.0 as a target framework to your maui app project.

Edit 1:
Also sometimes you need to add empty start point for netX.X build, looking like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your project name, directory name, and namespaces to remove all spaces and the corresponding underscores. Remove the bin and obj directories while you are at it.

I was having exactly the same issue as you, and the only similarity between your screenshots and my project that differed from the working samples I could find was the spaces/underscores. Removed all the spaces/underscores and the test project worked fine. My best guess is that when there is a space in the project name, it gets replaced with an underscore in some locations (i.e. namespace names) but keeps a space in others (i.e. the built library/DLL) causing some confusion with the project reference.